# Is that the Mystery Inc. Gang in the new Harley Quinn #1?

Tags: dc, comics, harley-quinn

I was just reading through the Rebirth Harley Quinn comics. While reading Harley Quinn #1 I noticed a familiar looking group of meddling kids in the background.

[image: Mystery Inc gang in HQ#1]

Is that them there? If so is there a reason for their appearance? Are the artists friends?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, it was the Scooby-Doo gang, as Harley appeared in two Scooby Doo comics as well.**

The Scooby Doo Team Up comics feature Scooby Doo teaming up with various famous characters. Harley Quinn was the featured character in two of these comics, Scooby Doo Team Up #12 and #21. In those, which are also sold by DC Comics, Harley appears in her more traditional jester costume, and is more closely tied to the Joker than she is in Rebirth. In the second of the Scooby Doo Team Up comics featuring Harley, Poison Ivy is a featured character as well. The first of these was released on September 23 2015, and the second was released on December 28 2016.

The first issue of Harley Quinn: Rebirth was released on August 3, 2016, between these two comics. So in between Harley's appearances in the Scooby Doo gang's comics, they made a cameo in hers.

Comment: To  get a bit pedantic, I'll bet that's not "officially" the gang in that issue, as odds are they can't use the character wherever they like, only in the licensed comics themselves.  But it's certainly "supposed to be" them.